# Insert spaces between concatenated captialized words with acronym support

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I need:

- "DerivateASK" should be changed to "Derivate ASK"
- "LiquidASKAnalysis" should be changed to "Liquid ASK Analysis"

How do I achieve it? Any regex in JavaScript would be appreciated.

I came up a solution till here:

```
 s.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z]*)/g,'$1 $2').trim()
```

The solution works for "DerivateASK" (this is changed to "Derivate ASK"), but the "LiquidASKAnalysis" changes to "Liquid ASKAnalysis" with no space after ASK.

Comment: okay, thanks @wiktor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
s.replace(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g, ' ')
```

Unicode-aware equivalent:

```
s.replace(/(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})|(?<=\p{Lu})(?=\p{Lu}\p{Ll})/gu, ' ')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV8OwT/1).  Note `\p{Lu}` matches any uppercase Unicode letters and `\p{Ll}` matches any Unicode lowercase letters.

**Details**:

- `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` - a location between a lowercase ASCII letter and an uppercase ASCII letter
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])` - a location between an uppercase ASCII letter and an uppercase ASCII letter followed with a lowercase ASCII letter.

JavaScript demo:

```js
const string = 'DerivateASK, LiquidASKAnalysis';
const regex = /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])/g;
console.log(string.replace(regex, ' '));
// => Derivate ASK, Liquid ASK Analysis
```